# Deploy android and IOS application developed by React-Native

Tags: react-native

I am the new bee in react-native. I wanna to build an Ios and Android application by using that technology. Currently, I used the window environment to build the react-native project ( build IOS and Android app), it is ok when I run an android app on real devices but can not on Ios devices.
I have researched the solution to that situation and know that I need to have a MacBook to build ios app on real devices. Is it real? So how can I use Window environment to build and run the app on real android and Ios devices?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

From react-native [document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html),

> Create React Native App is the easiest way to start building a new
>   React Native application. It allows you to start a project without
>   installing or configuring any tools to build native code - no Xcode or
>   Android Studio installation required.

If you don't touch any part of native code, you won't need MacBook and even Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I building a Push Notification using FireBase and I need to run it on real IOS and Android devices. Can I do that without MacBook?

Comment: @David I think that would be perfectly fine, since [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) is just pure javascript code that calls firebase API.

Answer (score 0):

**Create React Native App** is the easiest way to start building a new React Native application
you can create your react native setup on your pc by:

> npm install -g create-react-native-app

Then run the following commands to create a new React Native project called "AwesomeProject":

**create-react-native-app AwesomeProject**

> cd AwesomeProject
>   npm start

Awesome! you create your first react native application setup

Read More >> [getting started...](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

Comment: I think this not a solution for me. Because if you use that way your app just run on"Expo client app", not on the Real device.